# Using WCF REST Template 4.0, How to consume JSON via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, c#-4.0, rest

Using the WCF REST template 4, among cutting down on the amount of configuration needed, you no longer require an SVC file to host a REST Web Service.

Previously I could use an asp:ScriptManager to create a JavaScript proxy that i could use to call my WCF Web Services using AJAX, I only had to provide the path to my SVC file.

Now that there is no SVC file and the service factory is instantiated in the global.asax file, I am not sure how to call my operation contracts via JavaScript.

Is there a way round this, or a best practice regarding doing this with WCF 4?
Am I better using the old 3.5 model of svc files etc?

EDIT : Or is my best option to use jQuery $Ajax calls?

Thank you to anyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You were right. your best option would be to use jQuery `$.ajax()` calls.

If you happen to integrate test your service, you can try self hosting it and creating a proxy using `ChannelFactory<T>()` where T is your contract type.

Ex:
    var address = new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost:8080/YourWebService/Section/");
    var factory = new ChannelFactory(new WebHttpBinding(), address); // Use your desired binding here
    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior()); // Add your desired behaviors here
    var wcfProxy = factory.CreateChannel();